# how to calculate the specificity, sensitivity and accuracy from the 4 factors

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, sensitivity-specificity

Used decision tree method. Created treemodel for the combined datasets and tried to make prediction on test datasets to calculate error. Please help me on how to calculate the specificity, sensitivity and accuracy from the four status.

The following are the status:

- 'A' stands for contract finished, no problems
- 'B' stands for contract finished, loan not payed
- 'C' stands for running contract, OK thus-far
- 'D' stands for running contract, client in debt

Below is the code and output:

```
train.pred <- predict(treemodel,testdata, type="class")
table(train.pred, testdata$status)

train.pred     A     B     C     D
         A 39140  3540     0     0
         B   457  2227     0   145
         C    61     0 44686  5522
         D     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Specificity and sensitivity do not make sense in this context. They only make sense when you have "true positive", "true negative" and so on. There may be some sensible way to collapse your table into a 2x2 table and label the rows and columns so this is appropriate, but as of now, it's not sensible.

You could look at accuracy by adding up all the correct classifications (the main diagonal of your table) and dividing by the grand total.

(NOTE it looks like you have a typo in your table with no one in the D row)